# Line Integral of a Vector Field in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Let $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})=(x^{2}z,xy^{2},z^{2})$ and define a closed curve $C$ in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$ comprised of three straight line segments $C_{1},C_{2}$ and $C_{3}$ formed by the intersection of the plane $x+y+z=1$ with the planes $y=0,z=0$ and $x=0$ (respectively).

Sketch the curve $C=C_{1}\cup C_{2}\cup C_{3}$ in the $(x,y,z)$-space, and calculate $\displaystyle\int_{C}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ by considering each line segment separately. Be careful to make sure the orientation of each segment of $C$ is aligned with the other segments.

Below is an image that I have plotted for all four planes: orange represents $x+y+z=1$, yellow represents $y=0$, blue represents $x=0$, and red represents $z=0$. I am not too sure how to evaluate the line integral, and how to relate the curve $C$ back to $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})$ - appreciate any pointers I can get, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection points of $x + y + z = 1$ plane with $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$ planes are,

$A (1,0,0), B (0, 1, 0), C (0, 0, 1)$.

So our lines (all oriented in the same direction) are

$AB = (1, 0, 0) + (-1, 1, 0)t \, $ ($t = 0$ to $t = 1$)

$BC = (0, 1, 0) + (0, -1, 1)t \, $  ($t = 0$ to $t = 1$)

$CA = (0, 0, 1) + (1, 0, -1)t \, $  ($t = 0$ to $t = 1$)

$i)$ Now for our line integral along path $AB$

Please note $r(t) = (1-t, t, 0) \,$ and $\, r'(t) = (-1,1,0)$

$C_1 = \displaystyle \int_{t=0}^{1} (x^{2}z,xy^{2},z^{2}) dr = \int_{t=0}^{1} ((1-t)^2.0,(1-t)t^2, 0) r'(t) dt$

$C_1 = \displaystyle \int_{t=0}^{1} (0,(t^2-t^3), 0) \cdot (-1,1,0) dt = \int_{t=0}^1 (t^2-t^3) dt = \frac{1}{12}$

You can similarly find $C_2$ and $C_3$.

Comment: Thanks for this, really helped a lot. Was wondering if you could provide more justification on how to exactly know when the lines are oriented in the same direction? Does this lie in the points $(-1,1,0)$, $(0,-1,1)$, and $(1,0,-1)$ for $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$ respectively?

Comment: @LeonardKuan We first found the intersection points of the plane with the other $3$ planes. Now the orientation can be either clockwise or anticlockwise. It is not given. All it says is for the lines to be oriented in the same direction. So we can take $AB, BC, CA$ or $BA, AC, CB$. The starting line could be any. Just draw $\triangle ABC$, pick a direction and keep moving in the same direction. Also as we have to get vector in the direction $AB, BC, CA$, we do $B - A$, $C - B$, $A - C$.